# create a PR request in azure build pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops

Say we have following branches:

1. Master
2. Sprint
3. Stories

Stories can be merged to sprint (for sprint items) or Master (for hotfix) and we want is this:

1. Sprint branch to be deployed to PreProd Environment
2. If QA is happy, sprint branch will be merged to master and then deployed to UAT, then QA.

We wants to protect master or sprint branch, so they can only be changed via PR request.

Other than QA manually create a PR and then merge to master branch, I would like to do it in a build task. So I tried to use Azure CLI task to run a batch:

```
az repos pr create --auto-complete true --bypass-policy true --bypass-policy-reason "CI build" --repository JerryTestCI  --source-branch R_Current_Sprint --target-branch master
```

This gives me an error:
Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.

However, as my script runs in a build task, how can I login? I tried this, but my build will just hang on this command.

```
az devops login --organization https://XXX.visualstudio.com/
```

So is my idea the right way to do work? And if it is ok, how can I create and finish a PR request in build pipeline?

Comment: One possible google query is "az devops login non interactive". It yielded (among others) [this page on Ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows). I'm not sure it contains all the details, but it looks like a good step towards logging without typing a password.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answers below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And if it is ok, how can I create and finish a PR request in build
> pipeline?

### Solution 1

The easiest way would be to use [Create Pull Request Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest&targetId=f77d7bff-fef8-47d4-8c90-aa2b1c0ee245) with "Set Auto Complete" option checked.

### Solution 2

If you want to do it from CLI, generate PAT Token:

[image]

Save it as secret variable:

[image]

An use powershell to save it as [env variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#use-environment-variables)

```
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = '$(token)'
```

And then use any az devops command, it should be authenticated.

Comment: hi, I tried solution 2, when using cli command to login, it just hangs forever and no error was printed out
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = '$(pat)'
az devops login --organization "https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/"

Comment: You don't have to use az devops login anymore sorry (post edited), my mistake! After saving token in env variable use any of az devops module command, and it should be authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to install the [Create Pull Request extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest), it automatically creates a Pull Request for Azure DevOps or GitHub repository from Build or Release pipeline, supports also multi-target branch.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I'm the author.*

Comment: You should update your task so that it runs cross-platform!

Answer (score 0):

You can log in with the az devops cli via something like this:

```
echo $PersonalAccessToken | az devops login
az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/$OrganizationName project=$ProjectName
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

But then yeah, this should work just fine.